# Sequencing App-V to install/point to original application location

Tags: windows, sccm, appv

I am not sure if I am posting this on the right section. Also forgive my limited terminolgy.

Is it possible for the sequencing process to install the application in its original folder location?

For example, the locally installed application would install to **c:\Appfolder** and works without issue

After sequencing, the application folder location is then **C:\ProgramData\App-V\????????-????-????-????-????????????\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Appfolder**

The sequenced location will not work for the application as the **c:\Appfolder** seems to be hardcoded into other files called by the main exe. When the files that should be in **c:\Appfolder** are not found the program fails to start.

To test, I have tried copying the original locally installed folder to where it is expected to be, and the sequenced application starts successful upto a point then it fails again (probably registry and other settings are missing).

Edit: Sequencer/App-V is version 5.1

Comment: Have you attempted to PVAD sequence your application? https://virtualvibes.co.uk/understanding-the-pvad/

Comment: No, I haven't tried PVAD but will give it a try when I am back in the office. It does sound promising, but as the app has various depencies I am just curious about files that would install in other locations like Sys32 instead of C:\Appfolder. Thanks for pointing out another possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, I'm afraid you cannot. You need to fix your application to use a relative path instead of a full hardcoded path.

To understand why you can't you need to understand [how the app-v client works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIn5PX7EIvg). Checkout the video, it's short and gives you a quick introduction of the app-v container.

Comment: I figured as much based on other almost similar questions, but thought I would chance it. Unfortunately the app is old and the development house no longer exists so will read into other possible scenarios and solutions. The video links did clear up some misunderstandings. Thanks

Comment: You might want to checkout MSIX as a packaging format, if you are on Windows 10. 

It comes with support for fixups, which allow you to hook into app calls and redirect them.  Here is a demo I made at Ignite: https://youtu.be/f3Z7j1XEPgs?t=749

Comment: Yes, almost all our client OS's are windows 10. The MSIX package sounds like it could be a viable solution for the application as it sounds like it incorparates all required files into the package. Will only be able to test when I am back in the office, but for now will read moe into MSIX and download the demo of advanced installer. Thanks again